# Python: condensing multiple if conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

I have these statements:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if not "-a" in arg and not "-i" in arg and not "-r" in arg and not "-o" in arg and not "-s" in arg:
        print "Error: invalid argument \"" + arg + "\"."
```

There has to be a way to condense these statements to end up with less code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try using pythons [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module. It will make your life easier (avoids this mess) and your programs look and feel more professional.

Comment: Can you say in words what you are trying to test?  I think that might help clarify how to re-write this logic.

Comment: this is a really weird way to implement argument handling. for example what if you want to do something like `python script.py -f filename -o hypermode -l item1 item2 item3` etc. etc. Your current code format wouldn't work for that type of thing.

Comment: I want to test if `-a`, `-i`, `-r`, `-o` and `-s` is in every argument. If not, print the error response.

Comment: `and` or `or`?  The logic is very different.

Comment: Let me rephrase - I want to test all arguments. If an argument does not contain neither `-a`, `-i`, `-r`, `-o` nor `-s`, print an error.

Comment: perhaps you want to go if x not in ("-a", "-i", "-r", "-o", .. )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
valid = {"-a", "-i", "-r", "-o", "-s"}   # using a set, for efficiency
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:                 # loop over args
    if not any(v in arg for v in valid): # equivalent to code in question
        print 'Error: invalid argument "{}".'.format(arg) # using format string
```

But really, you should consider using a specialized parser for command line arguments (like [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)): this is not robust enough and will give you "false positives" and "false negatives" - see the comments.

Comment: This only works if all the args match the `"-[a-z]"` pattern, and if you're going to do that you may as well strip off the dash. `if arg.lstrip('-') not in 'airos': …`. Otherwise, if `arg` is something like `--awful` you'll have a false negative.

Comment: @kojiro OP is just checking if any of the command switches is in the `arg` variable. Granted, it's not very reliable, as the above will accept both `"-a"` and `"--angry"` as valid, but it's semantically equivalent to the code in the question. To make a really robust parser, `argparse` should be used

Comment: @kojiro yes, this gives "false negatives" as a command switch parser. But again, it's not my intention to build such a beast, I'm only writing a shorter version of OP's code - but OP's code is not robust enough to begin with

Comment: Sure, but these comments need to be made for future SO readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense them by doing:

```
if arg not in "-a-i-r-o-s":
    print "Error: invalid argument \"{}\".".format(arg)
```

But i'd recommend using the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module to do all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to test whether (e.g.) `-a` is *in* the argument, or whether `-a` *is* the argument? The latter would be more common. You could do something like this:

```
if arg.startswith("-") and arg[1:2] not in "airos":
    print "Error: invalid argument '%s'" % arg[:2]
```

If you really want to test whether `-a` is in the argument, easiest way is probably:

```
if not any("-" + c in arg for c in "airos"):
    print "Error: invalid argument '%s'" % arg
```

Comment: I want to test whether `-a` is _in_ the argument.

Comment: @user1676037 Does `-a` have to be in the first two characters of the argument string? If so then the solution is very easy. :)